# php - add new line after creating x divs

Tags: php

Hello :D i'm design a photo gallery in php . and i'm putting every photo in a div . i want to know how to add a new line automaticly after creating 4 divs
i've tried this

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST[save])){
    for($x=0;x<=4;x++){
        $f=fopen('image.html','a');
        fwrite($f,'<div style="width:300px;height:300px;"><img src="'.$_POST['picname'].'"></div>');
        fclose($f);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: looks like you only have 4, or is this inside another loop??

Comment: what i want is when i add 4 divs i want the page make new line automaticly